# How can I change the configuration of /etc/updatedb.conf file?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, locate, updatedb

Based on the man page of the command "updatedb", we can change and override the configuration of /etc/updatedb.conf using the below commands:

```
   --prune-bind-mounts FLAG
          Set PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS to FLAG, overriding the configuration file.

   --prunefs FS
          Set PRUNEFS to FS, overriding the configuration file.

   --prunenames NAMES
          Set PRUNENAMES to NAMES, overriding the configuration file.

   --prunepaths PATHS
          Set PRUNEPATHS to PATHS, overriding the configuration file.
```

But when I try to use them, there is no change. For example I expect the command below to change the flag to "no", but nothing happens:

```
sudo updatedb --prune-bind-mounts no
```

Just it takes a while to execute and exits without any warnings or errors, when I check the /etc/updatedb.conf content, it's the same as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These flags don’t change the configuration file; they affect the invocation of `updatedb` they are attached to, ignoring the configuration file.

Thus

```
sudo updatedb --prune-bind-mounts no
```

runs `updatedb` with `PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS` set to `no`, regardless of the value set in the configuration file.

If you want to change `/etc/updatedb.conf`, edit it.